# animate between css states?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can I animate between hover states?

Eg:

```
#menu ul li a {
    display:block;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #0488C5;
```

So the bottom border would rise up from 0 to 25px.

I'm not sure if this is possible with CSS, or if I'd have to use jQuery?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use CSS3 transitions, but their support isn't that great at the moment:

```
#menu ul li a {
    -webkit-transition: border .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: border .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: border .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: border .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

The syntax is: `element` `time` `easing`

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahallicks/2d3ew/2/)

Comment: I thing their support **is** great. Just IE9 lacking behind.

Comment: With prefixes ;-) I was referring to standard support. But thanks for the info!

Comment: For nice transitions, border needs to be set for both. http://jsfiddle.net/2d3ew/1/ animating from "none" to anything else is not supported (that's why your fiddle is jumpy and does weird things).

Answer (score 2):

Yep, just add a CSS transition.

in `#menu ul li a {`

just add:

```
-webkit-transition: border .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: border .5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: border .5s ease-in-out;
transition: border .5s ease-in-out;
```

You don't need an ms one by the way, IE10 doesn't use prefixes.

For loads more info, have a look at http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can do animations between css classes using [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/)

```
$( ".newClass" ).switchClass( "newClass", "anotherNewClass", 1000 );
```

You can also use it to animate css properties:

```
$( "#effect" ).animate({
    backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
    color: "#fff",
    width: 500
}, 1000 );
```

This will animate from the current background color, color and width, to the ones you specify.

Comment: 1. He didn't ask for classes. 2. jQuery UI would add like 200kb.

Comment: default you can not animate color in jQuery

Comment: You can specify a hover class and add it using jQuery's methods. I also provide the alternative of animating properties directly. CSS3 transitions are not as well supported as a jQuery UI solution. Granted, size would increase but 200kb isn't such a big deal these days.

Comment: @Mark I talk about jQuery UI, not jQuery

Comment: @Jeroen, oh, sorry, did not see that.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 transitions would do the job:

```
#menu ul li a {
    display:block;
    color:#FFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    -webkit-transition: border-bottom-width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: border-bottom-width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: border-bottom-width 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: border-bottom-width 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
    color:#fff;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    border-bottom: 25px solid #0488C5;
}
```